# Crossfading two Views continuously in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have already built an Alpha animation crossfading two images continously using class `Animation`.

Each image fades in and out. When the animation ends, it resets and restarts itself:

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        arg0.reset();
        arg0.startNow();
    }
});
```

Another image uses the exact same animation, but it is started with a delay. Therefore, image1 fades in, shows constantly, then as it slowly fades out, image2 fades in, shows constantly, and then as it slowly fades out, image1 fades in again and so on.

```
anim.setStartTime(AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis() + DELAY);
view.setAnimation(anim);
```

If the app runs without interference from the user, it seems to slowly get out of sync. When the app is paused, and then resumed, the animations are completely out of sync. I think the reason is because it creates separate threads without synchronization.

Is there a simple way to get it done in a synchronized manner?

The animation XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:startOffset="0"/>
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:startOffset="2000"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When app is on foreground the problem is the process time to start an animations makes it to out of sync.

I would suggest you to use [ViewFlipper.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) You may need to start and stop flipping in onResume and onPause in your activity or fragment.

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:auto_start="true"
    android:flipInterval="2000">

// YourViewsHere

</ViewFlipper>
```

You can set animations like;

```
flipper.SetInAnimation(this, Android.Resource.Animation.FadeIn);
flipper.SetOutAnimation(this, Android.Resource.Animation.FadeOut);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented something with it already. I wrote some comment here before but I was wrong so I removed them. I had to fiddle a bit with two extra RelativeLayout but it seems to work so far.